# Why is recursive static function is not behaving like expected?

Tags: php, recursion

The function below should return the next working day. It takes into account holidays and weekends.
The problem is the weird behaviour at the end (see image below code)

```
class test{

   private static $i;
   static function getNextWorkingDay(DateTimeInterface $dateTime) {
        self::$i++;
        dump("Iteration n°: ".self::$i. " Date: ".$dateTime->format('d/m/Y'));

        $dateTime = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($dateTime->getTimestamp());
        if (self::isWeekend($dateTime)) {
            dump("Iteration n°: ".self::$i." Weekend");
            self::getNextWorkingDay($dateTime->modify('next monday'));
        }
        if (self::isNotWorkable($dateTime)) {
            dump("Iteration n°: ".self::$i." Not workable");
            self::getNextWorkingDay($dateTime->modify('next day'));
        }


        dump("Iteration n°: ".self::$i. " This date should be returned and end the function: ".$dateTime->format('d/m/Y'));


        return $dateTime;
    }
}
```

[Testing with date = 2020-05-01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO8lR.png)

I expect 2020-05-04 but it returns 2020-05-02

Comment: Keep in mind that `modify()` is changing the `DateTime` object and `$dateTime = ...` replace the parameter value by a new instance.

Comment: return $dateTime->modify('next day'); ?

Comment: See this link guys [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO8lR.png). The last dump of the third iteration is dumping three times instead of one and that's the problem ... It seems like the function does not stop after a return.

Comment: What is "the weird behaviour"? What have you tried to debug it?